# Pytorch not installing using pip

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I'm trying to make a program that includes pytorch but I install it and it still says import torch cannot be resolved. I have tried all of the pips I can find and the official one multiple times but none of them work.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code in the same python enviroment where you are installing it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you able to show us what you have tried so far and the actual error your getting? What OS are you using? Sometimes PIP installation doesn't work (in Windows) if you do not have the admin rights or your firewall is blocking the pkg installations.